# Remove element from an array in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have below variable.

Dim strValues As String() with values "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"

I want to delete "4" from StrValues based on the string index without knowing the string value in vb.net. How can I do this?

Comment: Why not use a `List(Of String)` instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use Linq for simplicity:

```
Dim strValues = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"}
strValues = strValues.Where(Function(s) s <> "4").ToArray 'Removes all instances
```

Better yet, use a list:

```
Dim strValues = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"}.ToList
strValues.Remove("4") 'Removes first instance of "4" only
```

If you want to do it by value at index you could do something like the following (though these will remove all instances of the value):

```
Dim index = 3
strValues = strValues.Where(Function(s) s <> strValues(index)).ToArray
```

or

```
strValues = strValues.Except({strValues(index)}).ToArray
```

To remove or skip a given index (single instance only), you could do something like this:

```
Dim index = 3
strValues = strValues.Take(index).Concat(strValues.Skip(index + 1)).ToArray
```

Comment: I like your first answer above. How can I do that based on the index without actual string?

Comment: `strValues = strValues.Where(Function(s) s <> strValues(Index)).ToArray` In your circumstance `Index` would be 3.

Comment: Thanks. It gives compilation error!

Comment: You could also do: `strValues = strValues.Except({strValues(index)}).ToArray`

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't give me correct values. Please note the values of StrValues are coming from Split(",") method. Any idea for this case?

Comment: Nope. The source of the array should make no difference. If you're actually getting those errors you are either not using a recent .net framework or not explaining your issue well enough for me to understand.

Comment: Thanks. strValues = strValues.Take(index).Concat(strValues.Skip(index + 1)).ToArray works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Dim strValues As String() = New String() {"1", "2", "3", "4"}
 Dim strList As List(Of String) = strValues.ToList()
 strList.Remove("4")
 strValues = strList.ToArray()
```

Comment: Which instance of "4" will this remove (if there are ever multiple)?

Comment: Just the first occurrence (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by "delete", you could do a couple of things. First, if you're for a dynamically sized array, you may want to look into the [`ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.collections.arraylist) or [`List(of T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  This class allows you to add and delete objects to an array while resizing for you if necessary.  However, if you literally want to delete it from your array, you can set the value to `0` or `Nothing` or shift all the values in the array after it down one index.